# how to hide/show Imageview on Button Click for Custom Adapter Layout

Tags: android, listview

I have custom adapter for `ListView`. The `ListView` is in `activity_main.xml` and I have a `ImageView` in `CustomAdapter` layout which is populated with `ListView` using `CustomAdapter`.

My Question is I have to hide/show that image which is in custom layout with a button present in main layout. Like if there is 10 row in my `ListView` and 10 row have that image. I want to hide only for the particular row.

I hope you understand my question...Thanks in Advance

Here's my `ListViewAdapter`

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FileName> {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<FileName> filenames;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,int resource,List<FileName> filenames) {
        super(context, resource, filenames);
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        this.context = context;
        this.filenames = filenames;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView filename;
        TextView shorttext;
        ImageView imageView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.filename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            holder.shorttext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_desc);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lock);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Capture position and set to the TextViews<br />
        holder.filename.setText(filenames.get(position).getName());
        holder.shorttext.setText(filenames.get(position).getShorttext());

        return view;
    }
}
```

name = filenames.get(position).getName(); //getting the positin from listview
   filenames.set(name,FileName.isVisible = true); //getting error on isVisible

Comment: What you mean by hide?? hide image view or delete row??

Comment: I want to hide/show image view Present in my listview

Comment: So you have to pass status parameter in your adapter.

Comment: yes..like if user click on button the image get hide which is in adapter

Comment: first you have to know the position inn which row of imageView is to be hide/show, so do you know the position?

Comment: that imageview is in all row

Comment: No, you have mentioned in question that you want to hide/show a particular row imageview, so you must know the position of which row you want to take action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have writen a Sample code and tested**

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<FileName> filenames;
DBhelper dBhelper;dBhelper
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
ListView listView;
ImageView lock;
String name;

//temporary button i have added
Button lockBTN;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_filename);
    lockBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lock);

    filenames = getResult();
    listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, filenames);
    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    lockBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //giving statically position is 2
            int position = 2;

            // when you press menu button or any other button
            FileName fileName = filenames.get(position);
            //here you can set true-Show and false-hide imageview
            fileName.setVisible(true);

            //and update the list
            filenames.set(position, fileName);
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

//temporary data to show on listview
private List<FileName> getResult() {
    List<FileName> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] nameArr = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};
    String[] shortTextArr = {"ShortText1", "ShortText2", "ShortText3"};

    for(int i=0; i<nameArr.length;i ++){
        FileName fileName = new FileName();
        fileName.setName(nameArr[i]);
        fileName.setShorttext(shortTextArr[i]);
        //setting default is hide to imageview
        fileName.setVisible(false);
        fileNames.add(fileName);
    }
    return fileNames;
}
}
```

**FileName**

```
public class FileName {
private String name;
private String shorttext;
private boolean visible = true;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String _name) {
    this.name = _name;
}

public String getShorttext() {
    return shorttext;
}

public void setShorttext(String _shorttext) {
    this.shorttext = _shorttext;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}
}
```

**ListViewAdapter**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<FileName> filenames;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<FileName> filenames) {
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.context = context;
    this.filenames = filenames;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filenames.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filenames.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.filename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        holder.shorttext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_desc);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lock);

        //holder.filename.setPaintFlags(holder.filename.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Capture position and set to the TextViews<br />
    holder.filename.setText(filenames.get(position).getName());
    holder.shorttext.setText(filenames.get(position).getShorttext());

    // check weather image is to show/hide
    if (filenames.get(position).isVisible()) {
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return view;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView filename;
    TextView shorttext;
    ImageView imageView;
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_filename"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lock"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/lock"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lock"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/utilities_notepad_icon" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="232dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.77">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Item Title"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="35"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:text="Item Description"
        android:textColor="#999"
        android:textSize="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/lo"
    android:layout_marginTop="13sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to hide on button click which is present in my main layout

Comment: you want to hide/show imageView (custom.xml), when button is clicked which is in your main.xml? I 'm right

Comment: getting error on this line (position, FileName.isVisible = true); connot resolve symbol

Comment: give the position of the row which you want to take action.

Comment: i gave the position now getting the error on isVisble please help me out i am a newbie check the updated question

Comment: send me the activity.xml, custom.xml, MainClass, AdapterClass and Model Class on mohdnabil89@gmail.com

Comment: check your email

Comment: ya i'm checking

Comment: have you find the solution?

Comment: you have said that, One Button will be there in MainLayout. where it is, i did not find in your xml.

Comment: it doesn't matter i think soo

Comment: when i put the position 0 its removing only the first row image when i try to remove the image on second row it not being remove please help ?and thanks you so much

Comment: did you given the position 1 ?

Comment: Yes when i give 1 or 2 to the application crashes but when i give 0 its only hide the first row image but didn't show again

Comment: pls. post screen shot listView, and error log after adding 1 or 2 position

Comment: i had the given you the main activity java in that there is a listview code..and the error is Indexoutofbond index is 1 size is 2

Comment: you send me on mail?

Comment: mohdnabil89@gmail.com is this your email?

Comment: I send you the all mentioned file please check your mail @Mohammadnabil waiting for your help

Answer (score 0):

Take a extra variable in your `FileName` class.

```
public class FileName {
    public String name;
    public String shortText; 
    public boolean visible = true; // Set the default value to true. 
}
```

Now on external button click in your main layout, you might consider updating the list item accordingly. Just set the `visible` variable to `false` of that item you want to hide. Then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter to reload the data.

And yes, in your adapter, just check the value of `visible` attribute and then decide to hide/show the `ImageView`. So the `getView` function of your adapter should look like this.

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.filename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        holder.shorttext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_desc);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lock);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    // Capture position and set to the TextViews<br />
    holder.filename.setText(filenames.get(position).getName());
    holder.shorttext.setText(filenames.get(position).getShorttext());

    // Hide/Show the ImageView
    if (filenames.get(position).visible) holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use RecyclerView instead of ListView. RecyclerView got more performance than the ListView. Now a days all are using RecyclerView instead of old ListView, it is quite easy to use as well.
And for handling your case create a function to remove the file name you wanted to remove in the RecyclerViewAdapter class as below

```
removeImageView(position){
  fileNames.remove(position);
  this.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

notifyItemRemoved call will refresh the position in the recycler view and you will also get a nice view removing animation out of the box.